# Stress without strain

Tags: stress-strain

Suppose there are two rigid walls with some gap between them and a steel rod is placed within that gap firmly attached to both the walls(no strain can occur). If the temperature is increased by $T$,the rod cannot elongate since restrictions have been imposed at both ends. But the walls will impose equal and opposite forces on the rod. Internal stress as a result will be developed in the rod. Assuming $L,A,\alpha,Y$ as length,area and coefficient of thermal expansion and Young's modulus of steel,we would like to find the internal stress developed.

But the physics i studied till now always had strain to produce a stress. Now if i try to apply young's formula,i will get $Y=\frac{stress}{strain}$ and since strain is $0$,stress should also be $0$,then how is stress being produced?Also coefficient if thermal expansion also has the formula $\alpha=\frac{l}{LT}$,that makes $\alpha=0$. So isn't the problem contradictory?

Comment: Thanks a lot for commenting,the extension produced due to heating can be determined via $\alpha$,but how is the contraction due to the walls calculated?

Comment: @madness - heat the rod without constraint, then place between the rigid walls and apply stress to bring it back to the original (unheated) length...

Comment: Thank you,now since the contraction is equal to the extension of the rod,our equation is just $Y=\frac{stress}{contraction}$ from which stress directly follows,but what is the use of cross sectional area over here?Shouldn't it have a role to play in this regard?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with respect to the cross section, but the rod also shows volumentric expansion, which changes the cross section a little during heating. Since the stress required to return the rod inbetween the walls depends on the longitudinal expansion as well as the lateral expansion (change of area), the resulting strain will be nonlinear with temperature. Since thermal expansion is typically of the order of 10^-4 to 10^-3, this nonlinearity will be very small, though.

Comment: @madness note that the final equation in my answer to the post in the link I gave you is the same as the last equation in Chemomechanics answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Most generally, Hooke's law in the case of varying temperature in an isotropic elastic region is

$$\varepsilon_{ij}=\frac{1+\nu}{E}\sigma_{ij}-\frac{\nu}{E}\sigma_{kk}\delta_{ij}+\alpha\Delta T\delta_{ij},$$

where $\varepsilon$ is the strain, the indices $i$ and $j$ give the three-dimension orientation, $\nu$ is Poisson's ratio, $E$ is Young's modulus, $\sigma$ is the stress, [a repeated index indicates summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) (so that $\varepsilon_{kk}=\varepsilon_{11}+\varepsilon_{22}+\varepsilon_{33}$), $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) such that $\delta_{ij}$ equals 1 if $i=j$ and 0 otherwise, $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient, and $\Delta T$ is the temperature change.

This equation provides a shorthand way to summarize three normal strain expressions and three shear strain expressions.

For a temperature change of a rod (by definition, a long, thin object in which no lateral stresses can arise) under constrained uniaxial strain, assuming that no buckling occurs, we have $\sigma_{11}=\sigma$, $\sigma_{22}=\sigma_{33}=\sigma_{12}=\sigma_{13}=\sigma_{23}=0$, and $\varepsilon_{11}=0$, giving

$$0=\frac{\sigma}{E}+\alpha\Delta T;$$

$$\sigma=-E\alpha\Delta T.$$

Comment: Generalized Hooke's Law is derived [here](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/generalized%20Hooke's%20Law.htm), for example.