# Problem in thermal stress equation

Tags: elasticity, solid-mechanics

I came across this [derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/206938/376893) of thermal stress where the strain is given as $\frac { l_0 \alpha t}{l_0}$.

However, I believe it should be $\frac { l_0 \alpha t}{l_0(1+\alpha t)}$ to consider the force-induced reduction in length when not constrained between walls.

Specifically, at the given temperature, the length of the rod theoretically expands to ${l_0(1+\alpha t)}$ due to thermal expansion. However, the force from the wall compresses it by ${ l_0 \alpha t}$, resulting in a net change of $\frac { l_0 \alpha t}{l_0(1+\alpha t)}$.

This adjustment would lead to a modified thermal stress formula of $\frac{F}{A} = Y \frac { l_0 \alpha t}{l_0(1+\alpha t)}$.

Could you please confirm if my interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually due to kind of notation that we used in high school, when we were not fully familiar with applications of calculus in physics. The true relation is actually
$$d \ell = \ell \alpha dt$$
that is taken to be valid for any value of $\ell$.
the solution to this is
$$\ell = \ell_0 e^{\alpha t}$$
where in the small $\alpha t$ limit gives the high school result:
$$\ell \approx \ell_0 (1+ \alpha t)$$
Now you need to write the strain as $\frac{\Delta \ell}{\ell}$ which according to the first equation above is equal to $\alpha dt$.

Comment: But even if we follow your exponential formula of length then still how could we get strain equal to $\frac { l_0 \alpha t}{l_0}$ or $\alpha dt$ like in derivation that I provided in my question.

Comment: First replace $\Delta \ell/\ell$ with $d\ell/\ell$ and then use the first equation I wrote.

Comment: but I think that second equation given by you should be used to find strain. We are not finding instantaneous change in length so why use differential equation.

Comment: What you say is not correct. Look at equation (6.3) in Landau-Lifshitz Vol 7.

Comment: [https://youtu.be/i7Lx19UdFW8?feature=shared listen at 3:40 he used the word 'approximately' which means the normal formula in which we take strain as $\Delta \ell/\ell$ is not correct and instead of initial length $l_0$ before temperature raise we should take final length after temperature raise as denominator.

Comment: It does not mean you should take the final length. It means you have to integrate the expression over a changing length, as is done in this answer. The [true strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_\(mechanics\)#Logarithmic_strain) is symmetric for expansion followed by contraction. The [engineering strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_\(mechanics\)#Engineering_strain) is only an approximation and is not symmetric, which is why you ran into the problem described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer, said slightly diffently (engineer/physicist perspective): $l_{0}(1+\alpha t)$ is only correct to first order (small pertubation from equilibrium), as is expected  in the standard linear theory of elasticity. This means $\alpha t << 1$. Your proposed definition only adds a second order term we don't need to care about $\frac{1}{1+\alpha t}\approx 1-\alpha t$ so $\frac{\alpha t}{1+\alpha t} \approx \alpha t - (\alpha t)^{2}$

Comment: But my confusion was regarding that whether the equation of strain as used in derivation I provided is approximation or completely correct.

Comment: As the answers imply the strain is $\alpha t = dl/l \approx \Delta l /l$.